# Java Sort ArrayList inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Im having some issues sorting a ArrayList that contains ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> multiMarkArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

String line;
while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
    ArrayList<String> singleMarkArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
        singleMarkArray.add(word);
    }
    Collections.swap(singleMarkArray, 0, 1);
    multiMarkArray.add(singleMarkArray);
}

Collections.sort(multiMarkArray);
System.out.println(multiMarkArray);
```

Im getting the error **Collections** cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList>)

Can someone point me in the right direction to solving this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort all lists contained in `multiMarkArray` you should do

```
for (ArrayList<String> strings : multiMarkArray) {
       Collections.sort(strings);
}
```

instead of

```
Collections.sort(multiMarkArray);
```

This will sort the Strings in each list. But the sortation of the lists in `multiMarkArray` won't be affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can only sort Collections that contain elements that implement Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort, you need a sorting criterion. ArrayLists don't have a built-in sorting criterion because there's no natural way to compare two ArrayLists.

You have to provide a criterion by calling the version of `sort` with two arguments and passing a `Comparator<ArrayList<String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Collections [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) is applicable with "comparable" Object (`extends Comparable`):

> ```
> public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.
> ```

or you can send sort method with second parameter with your own Comparator:

> ```
> public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
>             Comparator<? super T> c)
> Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator.
> ```